# Aggregating rows in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a `data.frame` such as:

```
df = data.frame(id = c("a","b","c","d","e"), tid = rep("t",5), gid = c("A","B","C","D","E"), V1 = c("11","11","11","00","11"), V2 = c("11","01","11","01","01"), V3 = c("11","11","11","10","11"))
```

and I would like to aggregate rows that are identical between columns 4-6 (all columns but the first three). The first three column fields which correspond to aggregated rows should be the concatenation (comma separated) of their original values.

So for my example this would be the resulting `data,frame`:

```
> df
   id tid gid V1 V2 V3
1 a,c   t A,C 11 11 11
2 b,e   t B,E 11 01 11
3   d   t   D 00 01 10
```

What's the simplest/fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: right. thanks and sorry for the trivial question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to collapse a vector of values into a comma separated list, the best function for the job is `paste()` and if you combine that with the base `aggregate()` function, you get

```
aggregate(id~., df, paste,collapse=",")
```

which returns your desired output.

With the edited version of your question, you can use

```
aggregate(as.matrix(cbind.data.frame(id,tid,gid))~., df, paste,collapse=",")
```

If the columns you wanted to aggregate were character rather than factor, you could have just done

```
aggregate(cbind(id,tid,gid)~., df, paste,collapse=",")
```

Comment: `aggregate(id ~., df, as.character)` would also work.

Comment: I edited my question to a slightly more complicated case, if that's ok?

Comment: Normally it's not very polite to change your question after you ask it (clarifications are OK). Sometimes changing the question may lead to a completely different strategy and then all the time spent arriving at the first solution was wasted. So make sure your example reflects your actual needs as best as possible from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned "efficient" in your question. I would then suggest looking at `data.table`. Also, it's not clear whether you need `unique` or not, so I've shown my answer with `unique` since it matches your desired output:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ",")), 
          by = list(V1, V2, V3)]
#    V1 V2 V3  id tid gid
# 1: 11 11 11 a,c   t A,C
# 2: 11 01 11 b,e   t B,E
# 3: 00 01 10   d   t   D
```

Note that the result is a `data.table` and that your original `data.frame` has also been converted to a `data.table`.